# MongoDB creating Indexes with Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to createIndex in my collection and I am almost there.  However, I do not know how do I `partialFilterExpression` and `boolean` value in my code.  I tried following-

```
DBCollection TransmissionCharge = db.getCollection("Charge")
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src\\test\\resources\\datasheets\\Charge.json"))

            String name= "TrIndex"
            String Charge = null;
            while ((Charge= br.readLine()) != null) {

                DBObject record = (DBObject) JSON.parse(Charge);
                TransmissionCharge.createIndex(**record,name**)
            }
            br.close()
```

the MongoQuery is as follows-

```
db.Charge.createIndex({"_id.@Name": 1, "_id.InstanceId": 1, "_id}Recipient":1, "_id.Code":1 }, { "name": "RecipientIdx", "partialFilterExpression": {"_id.revenueRecipient": {$exists:true}}})
```

How do I get `partialFilterExpression` and `$exists:true` in my java code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: In addition to that your code is confusing. Please stick to the Java conventions and start your variable names with a lower case letter. Plenty of JSON frameworks allow to read in a JSON from an arbitrary input stream whch you can easily obtain via `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/datasheets/Charge.json")`